# Android Intent for Navigation - how can I ensure it will navigate me to the right place?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, google-places-api

I am working on an app that lets the user save a destination and later one-click navigate to that destination. In multiple cases, the location that is entered (which is being supplied by Google Place API autocomplete) and then clicked upon to navigate, brings me to the wrong place.

One example is looking for George Bush Intercontinental Airport. When i begin typing, and autocomplete suggestion is:

**George Bush Intercontinental Airport, North Terminal Road, Houston TX, United States**

However, when I launch an intent to navigate to this location:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + mapData.getPlace());
```

where mapData.getPlace() is a string equal to the address above, navigation launches and directs me to William P. Hobby airport.

Here is another example. When I search for Hobby Airport, the Place autocomplete suggests:

**Hobby Airport, Airport Boulevard, Houston TX, United States**

However, when I launch an intent to navigate (as above), it navigates me to

**DoubleTree by Hilton Hotel Houston, Hobby Airport**

It seems that the address supplied by AutoComplete is not a navigable address, and the navigation intent picks the closest suggestion.

One approach I have attempted is to filter the autocomplete results such that AutoCompleteFilter (as seen here https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete). My code for this is as follows:

```
    List<Integer> filterTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    filterTypes.add(Place.TYPE_STREET_ADDRESS);
    AutocompleteFilter filter = AutocompleteFilter.create(filterTypes);

    // Create and attach adapter
    mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mGoogleApiClient,MainActivity.CURRENT_BOUNDS , filter);
```

But this frequently causes "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten around this problem by geocoding the result from Autocomplete. I use the Geocoder object and take the 1st suggestion it supplies.

```
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.US);
    try {
        // Take first suggestion from geocoder object
        List<Address> coordinates = geocoder.getFromLocationName(mapData.getPlace(),1);

        //If a geocode result is supplied, use it. Otherwise, use the string from mapData
        if (coordinates.size() > 0){
            double latitude = coordinates.get(coordinates.size() - 1).getLatitude();
            double longitude = coordinates.get(coordinates.size() - 1).getLongitude();
            coords = (latitude + "," + longitude);}

        else{
            coords = mapData.getPlace();}
```

Then I pass coords into the the navigation intent.